# Preload wait 3 seconds before open page

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, timer, preload

I'm doing preload page. Here my code:

```
   <style>
    #page-preloader { ... }    
    #page-preloader .spinner { ...}
   </style>

   <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
   <script>
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
            $spinner   = $preloader.find('.spinner');
        $spinner.fadeOut();
        $preloader.delay(350).fadeOut('slow');
    });
   </script>    
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="page-preloader"><span class="spinner"></span></div>
    ...
```

All good, but i want to make some condition, and don't know how do it.
I need to preloader work minimum 4 second (even if page load for 1 sec) if session is empty.

Comment: What makes you think your users want to watch a preloader for 4 seconds for no good reason, most of them will probably leave.

Comment: In animation tells a story, and  a visitor must to see it

Answer (score 0):

Increase delay().

```
 <script>
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var $preloader = $('#page-preloader'),
        $spinner   = $preloader.find('.spinner');
    $spinner.fadeOut();
    $preloader.delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
});
```